# Deriving $|\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{2n}{k}|\leq (\frac{16\sqrt 3}{9})^n $ where $|(z-1)^2(z+1)|\leq \frac{16\sqrt{3}}{9}$

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

This question is from Bak & Newman's question 15, page 160:

$\mathbf{Q:}$ Show that $|(z-1)^2(z+1)|\leq \frac{16\sqrt{3}}{9}$ whenever $|z|=1$. Then deduce that

$$|\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{2n}{k}|\leq (\frac{16\sqrt 3}{9})^n $$

I tried the first part, but am clueless as to how I can get the $\sqrt 3$ out..

For the second part, I arrived at the step:

$$ |(z-1)^2(z+1)|^n =|(1+z)(1-z)^2|^n =|(1+z)^n(1-z)^{2n}|=|(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}z^k)(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^kz^k)|$$

So my question for this part is how can I manipulate the $2n$ in the second sum such that I am able to "combine" the sums to get the desired inequality?

Comment: Are you aware of Cauchy's integral formula and the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: Yes for Cauchy's integral formula but not for the maximum modulus principle at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first part: by letting $z=e^{i\theta}$ we have
$$ \|(z-1)^2(z+1)\|^2 = (2+2\cos\theta)(2-2\cos\theta)^2 \tag{1}$$
and the derivative of the RHS vanishes iff $\sin\theta=0$ or $\cos\theta\in\left\{-\frac{1}{3},1\right\}$. By straightforward computations the maximum modulus of $(z-1)^2(z+1)$ over the unit circle is $\frac{16}{9}\sqrt{3}$.
About the second part:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^k = [x^n]\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}x^j\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{j}(-1)^j x^j\right) \tag{2}$$
hence the LHS is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product between $(1+x)^n$ and $(1-x)^{2n}$, or the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\left((1-x)^2 (1+x)\right)^n$. By Cauchy's integral formula such coefficient is given by
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\|z\|=1}\frac{\left((1-z)^2(1+z)\right)^{n}}{z^{n+1}}\,dz \tag{3}$$
and the modulus of $(3)$, by the triangle inequality and the first part, is bounded by $\left(\frac{16}{9}\sqrt{3}\right)^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why do we use the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(2)$? I'm new to these topics so I am still somewhat clueless on this part..

Comment: @Stoner: In general, $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} a(k) b(n-k) $$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product between $\sum a(k) x^k$ and $\sum b(k) x^k$, by Cauchy's product / convolution.

Comment: Awesome its clearer to me now. Thanks again!